# Include Image in Transactional Email

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I would like to give new subscribers a $5 coupon for subscribing to the newsletter.
The best way (in my mind) to do this is to create a transactional email template (System > Transactional Emails) and set it to email in lieu of the default Newsletter Subscription Confirmation email.
The $5 coupon will be redeemed in a physical store so it will need to have a scannable barcode instead of a simple promo code which is why it will need to be an image.
I'm asking:
1) Is this possible?
2) Is there a better way of doing this?
3) If this is the best way, how do I embed an image into the email message?
Please let me know your thoughts, I greatly appreciate any help you can give me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your proposed solution will work without editing template files in your theme. Below I have created a simple sample template for you to paste in a new template.

System > Transactional Emails > Add New Template

Paste this into **Template Styles**

```
body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

Below is the whole template to paste in to **Template Content**.

```
<body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
            <!-- [ header starts here] -->
            <table bgcolor="FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <a href="{{store url=""}}" style="color:#1E7EC8;"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" border="0"/></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;"">Thank you for subscribing to our newsletter.</h1>
                         <p>Below you will find your $5 coupon to use in store.</p>
            <p><img src="[THE ABSOLUTE URL FOR YOUR IMAGE EG: http://www.melissastore.com/media/coupon.png" alt="$5 Off Coupon" title="Print This Email to Claim your Coupon In Store" /></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA; text-align:center;"><center><p style="font-size:12px; margin:0;">Thank you again, <strong>{{var store.getFrontendName()}}</strong></p></center></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Note the line that contains

```
<img src="[THE ABSOLUTE URL FOR YOUR IMAGE EG: http://www.melissastore.com/media/coupon.png" alt="$5 Off Coupon" title="Print This Email to Claim your Coupon In Store" />
```

You need to substitute the src with your own image's url in the above code. Upload the image using your FTP client.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is exactly what I needed. I feel so silly for not realizing I could enter html code into the email template. Duh! Again, Thank You! I really appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

You can add subscribers a $5 coupon image in Newsletter in File

```
app\locale\en_US\template\email\newsletter_subscr_confirm.html

app\locale\en_US\template\email\newsletter_subscr_success.html

app\locale\en_US\template\email\newsletter_unsub_success.html
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the correct location for all the Transactional Email templates.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

Just create a template like you'd do for any other email templates. Add image in there and make sure to assign this email as 'Newsletter Subscription Success' email.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up creating a new template as you suggested rather than editing the existing one since my coupon is a limited time promotion and I want the option to switch back to the default.